# Knowing if we are running in a VM programmatically

Tags: assembly, arm, virtual-machine, hypervisor, cpuid

I'm trying to find a way to know if my program is running in a VM programmatically. This needs to work on any OS and any architecture (x86, or ARM).

Using the CPUID in x86 with `eax=1`, we are able to see if the hypervisor bit is set to 1, and this will give us the info that we are running in VM. This seems to work pretty well, especially on any OS. However, it is not portable on the new M{1,2} CPUs.

**Is there any instruction similar to CPUID to get this hypervisor bit on ARM ?**

On windows, I only found the way of parsing the hardware info with WMI, and get the company names -> This will lead to parse all the VM company names which is not portable in the future.
On Linux, the `/proc/cpuinfo` file can also be parsed to get this information. But didn't find any similar way to get this in Windows nor OSX.

**Do you know any reg key or something similar to have such info ?**

My goal is just to know if we are running in a VM, don't really need anything else (Vendor name for instance is not needed).

Any lead would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can not trust `CPUID` on x86 either, since that is under the control of the hypervisor. Also it's not clear which bit you mean. The `VMX` bit just shows the virtual machine extensions are present not that you are running in a VM.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your answer, actually it makes sense, it won't be the machine's cpu, but one that is emulated by the VM. However [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits), it is specified that the 31st of `ecx` is for the hypervisor, and always equal to 0 when running on the hardware CPU. So when calling the `cpuid` instruction on a VM, what will happen actually ?

Comment: Do you just need it to work on commonly used VMs in default configurations, or are you also trying to detect a VM that may be actively trying to conceal its existence?

Comment: I just need a VM in default configurations for now, nothing fancy. This is for logging purpose. Though I'm curious to know how to detect a VM that is trying to hide

Comment: When you execute `cpuid` in a VM, it traps to the hypervisor, which can populate the registers any way it pleases before returning.  This allows it to emulate a different set of CPU features than the chip may actually have.  So in particular it can return to you with bit 31 of `ecx` cleared, emulating a machine that doesn't support virtualization.

Comment: I would guess that the question of detecting a VM that doesn't want to be detected is an ongoing topic of security research, likely with a constant arms race between researchers discovering leaks and VM vendors defeating them.  Timing tricks are presumably one avenue, though timer instructions like `rdtsc` can *also* be set to cause hypervisor traps.

Comment: @NateEldredge Timing of `cpuid.1` is indeed used as an effecting way to detect VMs (the Guloader malware loader does that, along with `ecx.31`). Usually, the timing also uses the OS time (on Windows for example `GetTickCount`) and there're some heuristics checking that `rdtsc` is more or less compatible with the OS time. Finally, a VM-exit on `rdtsc` seems to slow down some guests a lot, and disabling `ecx=1` (which is used for paravirtualization) also slows down some guests considerably. It's kind of a messy arm race :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, it is very insightful. I believe this is not reliable since it can be fixed over time :) How about ARM CPUs, is there a way to detect such thing ?